# How to convert an raster image to a web map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gis, raster

I have an image and it has simple road data and station data.  Although the image is simple, the data is large.

Now I want to convert the image to a web page so that I can manipulate the road and station to draw something near a station.

It will look a bit like a google map, but simpler.

How do I do this?

Here I found a [example](http://dev.filkor.org/2013/04/14/create-an-interactive-map-using-javascript-and-html-5-canvas/) .

Comment: Hi user1093380, please check my edit

Comment: Thank you. Hope somebody answer my question .

Comment: Sunny, if you can give a little more info I am sure we can help. Are you looking to make a web page just like that example and want to know how to process your image first? Or you want to make a map like that but one that is editable from the web page? What format is the image in now?

Comment: thank you ! I want to make a map like google map. And the image only has road and station .